# How do I discard staged files using git?

Tags: git

I have a bunch of staged changes and a bunch of unstaged changes. Is there a git command to completely discard all my staged changes and in the same time keeping my unstaged changes as is?

**I don't want the staged changes to exist anymore. I just want them out of this world, but I wanna keep my unstaged changes as is.**

Comment: Your unstaged changes are, in a sense, based on the staged changes. I don't know that there is a simple way to do what you want. The most straightforward might be to commit the two separately, then do an interactive rebase to remove the first commit (containing the original staged changes) . This might entail resolving some merge conflicts for the second commit (which contain the original unstaged changes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming staged and unstaged changes are non conflicting,

Here's how you can achieve this:

```
git stash save --keep-index
git reset --hard
git stash pop
```

First command [stash with --keep-index] will stash only unstaged files. Second [ reset --hard ] will get rid of all existing changes (which now include only staged files). The third [stash pop] one will unstash the previously unstaged files.

Alternate approach can be: 
Commit the staged files, stash the remaining changes, remove the top commit, pop the stashed changes. Like below:

```
git commit -m "temp commit"
git stash
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git stash pop
```

Comment: Actually, `git stash save --keep-index` saves exactly the same thing as `git stash save`: both make two commits, one for the index and one for the work-tree. The difference is that `git stash save` ends with `git reset --hard` and `git stash save --keep-index` doesn't do the `git reset --hard`. So you could just `git stash save; git stash pop` here. But that's equivalent to just `git reset` with no arguments.

Comment: (The second method, committing the index first, will do what the OP apparently wants.)

Comment: @torek `git reset` will take files from staging area back to working area. If there are 2 staged files and 3 changed unstaged files, doing `git reset` will simply put 2 staged files back in to working area which will now have 5 changed files.

What OP wants I guess is removing files in staged area entirely while keeping the 'just changed [And not staged]' files intact.

Comment: `git stash save --keep-index` only stashes working area files keeping the files in the staged area intact. Hence, the first solution works as in a 3 step process, it 1) Stashes working area files 2) Removes staging area files 3) Brings back originally stashed working area files. 

Doing just `git reset` will not achieve the goal.

Comment: No, `git stash save --keep-index` makes the *same* two commits as any other `git stash`. What the `--keep-index` flag does is change the final act of `git stash` so that instead of `git reset --hard` (to match `HEAD`), it adjusts the index and work-tree to match the saved index commit. The `git stash` code is being converted away from shell script, so this is clearer in older versions of Git, but it really doesn't change the *saved* commits at all.

Comment: `git stash save -k` stashes the staged changes as well, so when you run `git stash pop` it will return you back to the initial state with all changes still exist.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution - which does not involve creating tmp commit (`git stash` actually creates tmp commit too):

First, create a patch between the **Index** and the `HEAD` commit, save to a tmp file:

```
git diff --cached -R > ~/tmp.patch
```

*Notice the `-R` option to reverse the direction of the diff.*

Second, reset the **Index**:

```
git reset
```

Finally, apply the patch to the **Working Dir**:

```
git apply ~/tmp.patch
```

Comment: Reset the index with `git diff reset`? Was it a typo for `git reset`?

Answer (score 0):

**To unstage all files** (see comments : not what OP wanted) simply

```
git reset
```

(`HEAD` is implied when no ref is given)

Your local changes are kept, but the index (staging area) is cleared.

Comment: I *think* the staged changes should be discarded completely, not simply folded back into the set of unstaged changes.

Comment: @chepner Oh. Now that I reread the question, I think you might be right. Let's hope OP will precise it.

Comment: Yes.. I should've read your comments. Now all my changes are mixed up but still kept :-/

Comment: @Doodlemeat Aw, geez. Sorry. I was in the process of writing an alternative, but now I guess the problem is different.

Comment: `git reset --mixed` (or `git reset` with no arguments) should do what was asked-for. The accepted answer achieves exactly the same thing, after all.

Comment: @torek no, `git reset --mixed` only affects the index, while the OP wants to affect the working dir too.

Comment: @NghiaBui: I think I understand: if, say, file F in the commit reads "I am original F" and in the index reads "I am new file F" and in the work-tree reads "I am new file F" (i.e., both index and work-tree copies match but neither matches the HEAD commit), the OP wants file F in index and work-tree to go back to matching the committed version. It's true that `git reset --mixed` won't achieve that—but neither would git stash.